# golang: how to print data from running goroutine at fixed intervals?

Tags: go

I'm having some trouble understanding channels in golang. As far as I know channels are the correct way to publish data to the console at a given time interval.

So say i have a goroutine that is doing work, and then in my main loop i would like to print data from that goroutine every second.

How would something like this be coded? A simple example would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Any goroutine can `fmt.Println` whenever it wants. No channels are required for that, though you might use them to make sure two goroutines don't write simultaneously. If you want to use a channel to interrupt your goroutine once a second, channel writes won't actually interrupt anything; you'd have to use `select` to check for a message from `time.Tick` or whatever. So I think we need to know more about what your code currently looks like and exactly which aspect of printing periodic updates you can't currently do in order to answer.

Comment: Remember that the `log` package provides the `Logger` interface. "A Logger can be used simultaneously from multiple goroutines; it guarantees to serialize access to the Writer." http://golang.org/pkg/log/#Logger

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can have some protected shared state in memory that you update from your long running process. Then you have a timer that triggers this shared state check every second.
Here is a quick example: http://play.golang.org/p/gfGvhHUWIc

Code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

type Progress struct {
    current string
    rwlock  sync.RWMutex
}

func (p *Progress) Set(value string) {
    p.rwlock.Lock()
    defer p.rwlock.Unlock()
    p.current = value
}

func (p *Progress) Get() string {
    p.rwlock.RLock()
    defer p.rwlock.RUnlock()
    return p.current
}

func longJob(progress *Progress) {
    i := 0
    for {
        time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
        i++
        progress.Set(fmt.Sprintf("Current progress message: %v", i))
    }
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("test")
    c := time.Tick(1 * time.Second)
    progress := &Progress{}
    go longJob(progress)
    for {
        select {
        case <-c:
            fmt.Println(progress.Get())
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: IMHO the `sync.RWMutex` looks better as an anonymous member, so you can just do `p.Lock()` instead of `p.rwlock.Lock()`: eg http://play.golang.org/p/2ewAmCCaVu

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass data from one routine to another you can do it like that

```
package main

import "fmt"

func routine(output chan int) {
    for i := 0; i < 1000; i++ {
        output <- i
    }
    close(output)
}

func main() {
    ch := make(chan int)
    go routine(ch)
    for i := range ch {
        fmt.Printf("%d ", i)
    }
}
```

But this is not quite you asked for, you wanted a status of routine every second. For this a channel is not a good solution. A variable shared between two routines will solve the problem. One routine updates it, another routine reads it every second.

Answer (score 0):

You easily print the data periodically as we are printing the current time here.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    ticker := time.NewTicker(time.Second)
    go func() {
        for t := range ticker.C {
            fmt.Println("Current time:", t)
        }
    }()

    // Wait for 10 seconds
    time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)
    ticker.Stop()
    fmt.Println("Ticker stopped")
}
```